# React js Material Ui TextField default value doesn't change

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to change default value of TextField when state change but it doesn't work. I guess it is doesn't re-render.

```
 <TextField
     multiline={true}
     rows={15}
     disabled
     id="outlined-basic" label="" variant="outlined"
    defaultValue={!isEn?data.data[0].description:data.data[0].descriptionLocalization.en}
/>
<Button style={{position:"absolute",right:"20px",bottom:"5px"}} onClick={changeStateIsEn}>Save</Button>}
```

Comment: Nothing here changes the state.  Do you have a more complete example to demonstrate the problem?

Comment: There is a button for change the state and all is   that

Answer (score 9):

Default value is not meant to be changed with state.

You should set the `value` for reflecting the default value

```
<TextField
  multiline
  rows={15}
  disabled
  id="outlined-basic" 
  label="" 
  variant="outlined"
  defaultValue="Something that will stay there initially only"
  value={!isEn ? data.data[0].description : data.data[0].descriptionLocalization.en}
/>
```

Answer (score 3):

Update the `key` of Element or Container after Default value Change

Comment: I think using `key` is right. Credit for arcmode https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/1328#issuecomment-198087347

Comment: give this man more upvotes, no other post mentions this

Answer (score 2):

There are two parts missing to your TextField component that is required to tie the input to state.

1. As user Mohammad Fasial said, the `defaultValue` prop is only for the default value the component will have. The correct prop you're looking for is `value`. State will need to equal `value`.
2. To listen for changes when the user inputs new information into the `TextField` input, you'll need to use the `onChange` prop. The `onChange` prop (on change listener) let's you provide a function as an argument to run when the input value changes. In this case we want to set `onChange` to run `setExampleState` to set the state to the value of the input field by using the `event.target.value` property.

```js
 
function ExampleComponent(){
  const [exampleState, setExampleState]  = useState([]);
  ...

 return (
   <>
    <TextField
        multiline={true}
        rows={15}
        disabled
        id="outlined-basic" label="" variant="outlined"
        defaultValue={!isEn?data.data[0].description:data.data[0].descriptionLocalization.en}
        value={exampleState}
        onChange={(event) => setExampleState(event.target.value)}
    />
    <Button style={{position:"absolute",right:"20px",bottom:"5px"}} onClick={changeStateIsEn}>Save</Button>
  </>
 );
}
```

To learn more about the different properties TextField has, you can look at the [TextField API Documentation](https://material-ui.com/api/text-field/). There are also a lot of [TextField code examples](https://material-ui.com/components/text-fields/) that can be expanded on the Material-UI site as well.